# Laravel session/cookie in google app engine

Tags: laravel

I have set up laravel in google app engine using the instructions from this url https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/ but when I try to use my login form (which has Redirect::intended() in its logic) I notice that the laravel_session cookie does not get created in my browser.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There 2 things you should have in mind:

1. mcrypt encryption extension is been supported by google app engine since May 2014.
2. The problem with the laravel_session cookie can be resolved by adding    "output_buffering = on" at php.ini in base folder.

Don't forget to restart the google app engine instance (even locally)

Comment: Useful info but still this doesn't solve my problem.