# Google App Engine Front Controller removes Cookies from Response Header

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cookies

Google App Engine's Front Controller removes the cookies from the response header set by my Laravel Framework 8.83.4 / PHP 7.4 application.

Cookies are being set in the browser properly when hosted locally. But, they are not set in the browser when I hosted it on Google's App Engine. So, Users can't persist the login session.

**Chrome Headers dump :  http://localhost:8000/login**

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2022 07:03:43 GMT
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2022 07:03:42 GMT
Host: localhost:8000
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ey <some cookie hash> idGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Tue, 15-Mar-2022 09:03:42 GMT; Max-Age=7199; path=/; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eym <some cookie hash> FnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Tue, 15-Mar-2022 09:03:42 GMT; Max-Age=7199; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.13

Request Headers:
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJ <some cookie hash> GFnIjoiIn0%3D
Host: localhost:8000
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36
```

**Chrome Headers dump : < App Engine Hosted Site URL >**

```
General:
Request URL: <App Engine Hosted Site URL>
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 142.250.182.116:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 2651
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 15 Mar 2022 07:05:17 GMT
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cloud-trace-context: 1c3fedeeb3822b2833cbe2ce676d5497

Request Headers:
:authority: <App Engine Hosted Site URL>
:method: GET
:path: /login
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
referer: <App Engine Hosted Site URL>
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36
```

Here is the snip of **index.php**. I tried dumping the response (Commented below). My application is properly adding cookie to the response header. But, front controller removes it I think.

**Index.php**

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
);

// dd($response); // Response contains cookie. Headers are similar to the locally hosted app.

$response->send(); // Response doesn't contain cookie. Front controller is removing the cookie I think.

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Some people have discussed to handle cookie related functions at the top of each and every HTML page. But, that is not convenient and scalable for us.

If using our own php server instead of Google App Engine's Front Controller is the solution, Let me know the correct way to set **entrypoint** in **app.yaml**

Please guide me to the correct way to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: App Engine does not remove your cookies. **curl** is not a session-based tool to use for debugging sessions. Edit your question and show a **browser** response and request.

Comment: Thanks John, I just edited the question. However, I didnt notice any difference in the response when I see logs in chrome.

Comment: In your edit, I do not see cookies being set in the HTTP response. Clients do not set cookies on the server, servers inform the client to save data via cookies.

Comment: Hi John, Sorry I am bit new to this. Consider, the cookie laravel_session for instance. The server has to send this cookie in its response header. So that my browser will set/save the cookie. But, I didn't see any cookie field in front controller response.

Comment: Added "set in the browser" term to avoid confusions.

Comment: Show the Laravel code that sets a cookie and returns an HTTP response. You are making an incorrect assumption that App Engine removes your cookies - it does not.

Comment: https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/master/Middleware/StartSession.php     Hi John, please check this file which contains addCookieToResponse  function necessary for adding cookie to response. These are auto included code default in laravel. I didn't do any customisation.

Comment: Further, I have checked before $response->send() in index.php, the response had the cookie contents in header, as I mentioned in the post. So, this addCookieToResponse function works properly. But, for some reason the cookies are getting removed when it comes out of app engine.

Comment: Your question does not show the source code of your application that processes an HTTP request, sets cookies, and returns an HTTP response.  Create a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi John, I create a simple app engine php app as you said with cookie user=Robot. It is working properly. Some issue is there with Laravel  not properly working with app engine I think. Let me go deep into Laravel and find what might be the issue. 

Hosted here : https://cookie-test-344307.uc.r.appspot.com/


<?php  
setcookie("user", "Robot");  
?>  
<html>  
<body>  
<?php  
if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {  
    echo "Sorry, cookie is not found!";  
} else {  
    echo "<br/>Cookie Value: " . $_COOKIE["user"];  
}  
?>  
</body>  
</html>

Comment: Can you try this solution from the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27789211/15803365)